# Time delay not working properly

Tags: java, netbeans

In my program what i am doing with the following code, is pressing (automatically) a button in certain time intervals (time provided by the user) for a certain times (number of times taken from the user). But the thing is that this some times fail to work properly. I mean if i set the time to 1.5 seconds and do it; 9 out of 10 times it does at 1.5 second gaps but the 10th time i run it, it rushes fast; clicks the buttons in time intervals less than a second. (Note here 9 out of 10 is just for example - it is not the exact figure)

Code:

```
double y = 1000 * (Double.parseDouble(t2.getText()));
int zad = (int)y;
        final Timer timer = new Timer(zad, new ActionListener() {
    int tick = 0;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Success" + ++tick);
              jButton7.doClick();
              final int col = Integer.parseInt(t3.getText());;
      if (tick >= col) {
        ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
        jButton6.setVisible(true);


      }

    }
  });



  timer.setInitialDelay(0);
  System.out.format("About to schedule task.%n");
   timer.start(); 
  System.out.format("Task scheduled.%n");
```

Hope i make sense and sorry if i don't, i am new to java. If you don't understand my question please just ask me where you couldn't understand me and i would elaborate that part to you.

**Update**: I figured out when it happens. See if the process is going on and i close that jframe and click the button to do it again, it shows this error. But when i close that window i want it to stop.

Comment: What kind of `Timer` class is that? It isn't [Java's `java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) obviously.

Comment: @cimnine: [Swing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

Comment: What happens if you set the initial delay equal to `zad`?

Comment: @Brian I dint try that but i think that it right now does not give any initial delay it would even pause for 1.5 seconds in the start; but that does not really matter i think. What do you say?

Answer (score 2):

As said on the docs: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#stop()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#stop%28%29), method `stop`:

```
 Stops the Timer, causing it to stop sending action events to its listeners.
```

So, when you call `stop`, the last action is performed. Immediately after the one that has been called.

Your code should be:

```
double y = 1000 * (Double.parseDouble(t2.getText()));
int zad = (int)y;
final Timer timer = new Timer(zad, new ActionListener() {
    int tick = 0;
    boolean itsOver=false;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Success" + ++tick);
      final int col = Integer.parseInt(t3.getText());

      if (! itsOver)
      {
          jButton7.doClick();
      }
      if (tick >= col) {
        itsOver = true;
        ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
        jButton6.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
});



timer.setInitialDelay(0);
System.out.format("About to schedule task.%n");
timer.start(); 
System.out.format("Task scheduled.%n");
```

Comment: Hey i dint get you... because most of the time my program works... can you please elaborate or shoe me what/how to change?

Comment: Could you please edit the formatting once, i cant understand clearlY

Comment: Excuse-me, I missed some spaces

Comment: Can you also explain what does it do? please

Comment: Of course: when `tick` count comes to end, it sets a boolean variable to true. Before every call to `doClick()` it tests this variable. As long as it is `false`, it knows that it has not ended and it is not the last 'ghost' call.

Comment: still dint get you man. Sorry but i am new to java and also i am just 15 years. Could you please explain a bit more. please. and sorry

Comment: oops, syntax error you have put the col declaration in a if statement. So there is a error at line "if (tick >= col) {"

Comment: I'm not sure what else explain... Your code executed the `actionPerformed` repeatedly until you called `stop()`. But, when `stop()` is called, the `actionPerformed` method can be called once more.  What I did is just adding a lock, a boolean variable that is set to true just before calling `stop()` and checked just before calling `doClick`. This way, you get sure that `doClick` is never called after  `stop()`.

Comment: i will definately try this many times and then tell you whether this works. But the thing is that if the problem was due to this; it should have occured all the times. but my problem occures only some times. Not always

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45481/discussion-between-daksh-shah-and-oscar-perez)

Comment: No it doesn't solve the problem. I figured out why it is happening